# PHP. How to pass variable and auto redirect to another PHP file

Tags: php, variables, session

I'm developing app for *Facebook*. Here when user open application should be checked If user already exists in database. I think I will use `$_SESSION`to pass *user's Id* to `checkIfExsists.php`

So my *FacebookGetId.php* looks like:

```
<?php
...
$id = $user_profile['id'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
?>
```

So `$id` for now is i.e. `'12345'` I just don't know how to make automatically redirect to `checkIfExsists.php` to check If that Id already exsists in database.

It should be something like: When application is launched, It should take *User's Id* and automatically redirect to `checkIfExsists.php`and pass that Id.

If user exists `checkIfExsists.php` should redirect user to `application.php`, if not exists - It should redirect to `registration.php`

Comment: If user exists `checkIfExsists.php` should redirect user to `application.php`, if not exists - It should redirect to `registration.php`

Comment: You can use `http_redirect("relpath", array("name" => "value"), true, HTTP_REDIRECT_PERM);`.
for more information Visit this[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php), it will help you.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to check Facebook User's ID already exists before lauching app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226758/how-to-check-facebook-users-id-already-exists-before-lauching-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [header](http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php) function

```
<?php
...
$id = $user_profile['id'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
header('Location: checkIfExsists.php?id='.$id);
?>
```

on the checkIfExsists.php get the variable with

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

That would solve your problem the way you want it to be solved, but, this isn´t neccesarilly the way it should be solved, maybe inside checkIfExists.php should be a class instead of structured code with a public function to check existance `checkExistance`, so you will then just need:

```
include_once(checkIfExists.php);
$check = new checker();
$exists = $check->checkExistance($id) ;
```

this way you do not have to be jumping between files and you can have a better way to re-use code,
regards.

Comment: No need to pass the ID along with the URL, the ID is allready set in a SESSION

Comment: then the whole FacebookGetId.php is obsolet, cause all to do is to start a session on the checkIfExsist.php and get the id with $_SESSION['id']

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but It returning me blank page, It shouldn't be blank, in `checkIfExsists.php` I'm using `session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id']; 
echo $id;` and in top of page trying to print errors: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);` but still empty, why can I get this problem?

Comment: I don't know what you do with the $id on the checkIfExsists.php but when you want to validate is i guess you check it against a Database. So when you verify that the id is existant you should implent a if function with another header.

For example:
if($id == $validate_id) {
header('Location: application.php');
} else {
header('Location: registration.php');
}

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. I missed `;` that's why was blank screen.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $id = $user_profile['id'];
 $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
 header('Location: checkIfExsists.php');
?>
```

And on the checkIfExsists.php page, retrieve the variable so:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $id = $_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but It returning me blank page, It shouldn't be blank, in `checkIfExsists.php` I'm using `session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id']; 
echo $id;` and in top of page trying to print errors: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);` but still empty, why can I get this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `header('Location:url_of_your_page.php?fbid='.$id)`. [php header function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php)

**FacebookGetId.php**

```
<?php
    ...
    $id = $user_profile['id'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    header('Location:checkIfExsists.php?fbid='.$id)
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but It returning me blank page, It shouldn't be blank, in `checkIfExsists.php` I'm using `session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id']; 
echo $id;` and in top of page trying to print errors: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);` but still empty, why can I get this problem?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas may be your `$_SESSION['id']` has an empty value, try adding a string to your `echo`, **eg.** `echo "Facebook ID : ".$_SESSION['id']`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it via GET and header for example :)

```
header('Location: checkIfExists.php?userID=12345');
```

in checkIfExists.php

```
echo $_GET["userID"]
```

or in checkIfExists.php just start sessions a load ID from session :)