# Using php header Location to exchange messages between pages with POST

Tags: php, post, message

I am using already this code:

```
<?php
// [...]
ELSE IF(isset($_GET['msg'])){
    echo "<div id='noticePanel' class='panel panel-success'><div class='panel-heading'>
    <h2 class='panel-title'>Good job!</h2></div>
    <div class='panel-body'><h4>".addslashes(strip_tags(trim(@$_GET[msg])))."</h4></div></div>";
    }
//[...]
?>
```

Which is called from other pages if some operation goes well:

```
  if ($result){
      header("Location:index.php?msg=DB updated succesfully");
      exit;
  }
```

**BUT** as you may imagine, it is not clean. Working, but not the best.

Can anybody tell me if I should move it to a **POST** request or if this code is "widely" used to exchange status messages between pages?

And, in case of the POST, can someone write down some code or redirect me to a page where this is explained well? I searched already of course, I found [THIS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) from mozilla, [THIS](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) with jquery and in general searching "send post php header" on google.
But I just can't understand how to do it.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: I am wondering why you still use something like this, why there is no framework or something else can manage this stuff for you, but anyway  in short you should call different template files for success/fail from one output file

Comment: @MohammadAlabed I'm using it because I used to develop websites in the 90's. Now I'm just a poor sysadmin who prefers plugging cables to switches than developing websites :/

Comment: Please do not downvote it, if there is something I am missing let me know, I am not going against any rule here to have questions downvoted. I'm not skilled and if i'm asking here is because i did not find the solution on google. Using another framework is not a solution for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you prefer to keep your code pure

i just suggest you to do not send the message in GET/POST

just send the status like

```
index.php?status=success
```

then check the status in result file

```
if(isset($_GET['status']) AND $_GET['status'] == success){
   echo "bla bla";
}elseif(isset($_GET['status']) AND $_GET['status'] == fail){
   echo "bla bla";
}else{
   //do something
}
```

**EDIT**

If you have many messages, then you can create array

```
$message = [
  'success' => 'success message here',
  'fail' => 'failmessage here',
  'notFound' => 'not found message'
];

$status = ( isset($_GET['status']) AND 
            isset($message[$_GET['status']]) )?$_GET['status']:'notFound';

echo $message[$status];
```

Comment: This is the code I was using before, but then I had too many IF for every message I wanted to print. I wish to send parameters/arguments. But yes, you got what I wanted and I thank you for that!

Comment: if you have many messages, create messages array, or create messageProcess function and keep your code short and clrear

Comment: It's okay, I solved with the session(). I feel more confident in working with tools I know and this page is only used by myself and few others, locally. No need to complicate things, simply make them easier to read ;)

Comment: Nice! Ok i like this with arrays! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I think i'm going to go with this: [PHP. How to pass variable and auto redirect to another PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228248/php-how-to-pass-variable-and-auto-redirect-to-another-php-file)

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $id = $user_profile['id'];
 $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
 header('Location: checkIfExsists.php');
?>
```

And on the checkIfExsists.php page, retrieve the variable so:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $id = $_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

## New code

```
session_start()
// [...]
ELSE IF(isset($_GET['msg'])){
    echo "<div id='noticePanel' class='panel panel-success'><div class='panel-heading'>
    <h2 class='panel-title'>Good job!</h2></div>
    <div class='panel-body'><h4>".addslashes(strip_tags(trim(@$_SESSION['msg'])))."</h4></div></div>";
    }
```

And..

```
session_start();
if ($result){
          $_SESSION['msg'] = "DB updated!";
          header("Location:index.php?msg");
          exit;
      }
```